# My ajax form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Yesterday I was advised by another user to start looking into Ajax coding to improve my application development skills.

I was testing form submissions. However My form is not submitting. I am only new to ajax so I have been following some tutorials on how to do ajax online so any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="../scripts/jquery.1.11.2.min.js">    </script> 
    <form id="form" action="" method="POST">
        <textarea id="question" name="question" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; resize: none;"></textarea>
        <button id="formsubmit"> Submit</button>
    </form>
    <textarea id="response" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; resize: none;"></textarea>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#formsubmit').on("click",function(){
                $.post("submit.php", { question: $('#question').val() }, function(data) {
                    $('#response').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

My goal here is to get the user input and show it in a textarea beneath it. I don't want the page to refresh.

My php code to process this is :

```
<?php
    $q = $_POST['question'];
    echo $q;
?>
```

Comment: You should run the AJAX event under the `submit` event of the form (using `preventDefault()` to stop the normal submission) instead of click of the button.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the response. I used the exact code that you added. However its not printing the answer in the response textarea. I have added the e.preventDefault() and its still not working.

Comment: You should not change the original code as that will invalidate the answers. Just put the most current version below the original question.

Comment: @jeroen thanks :) I will roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$('#formsubmit').on("click",function(){` click event, Use this:

```
$('#form').on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//prevent default submission
  //your code of ajax
```

You should use `<input type="submit"` instead of `<button id="formsubmit"> Submit</button>`

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/47hh9pp8/)

Comment: I would change `$("#formid")` to be more inline with the original post. `$("#form")`

Comment: @Manwal thanks for the working example. I have updated my code with the two lines you wrote above. It is still not echoing the user input

Comment: @DetectiveClarke Is your page is not reloading? because if it is your jquery code not working. If your ajax is working you can see ajax request response in Developer Tools ( Network Tab ).

Comment: @Manwal It just seems to not be echoing out the result. I have my new code with your lines and changes and its not printing the result.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke You should change your output element to something like a `div` as a `textarea` does not have html content. Or use `$('#response').val(data);` instead.

Comment: @jeroen I have added in a <div> tag and it is still not working. I always thought I could send the output to a textarea! thanks for the tip Ill remove the textarea. I also added in the  code :     $('#response').val(data);
and its still not working

Comment: @DetectiveClarke Check the console to see what is happening and what you get back.

Comment: @jeroen how do i check the console?
console.log?

Comment: @DetectiveClarke That's part of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke if you are using Google chrome or mozila firefox simply press `F12`

Comment: @jeroen thanks for the tip! there was a problem with my file referencing of my jquery.js file. I have used the    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  for the time being. Still the user input is not displaying

Comment: @jeroen even after using preserve log There doesnt seem to be any obvious errors. everything is loading.
This leads me to believe that the error is in the ajax function and the php code

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to change the button input element. You can try this one

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>
    <form id="form" action="" method="POST">
        <textarea id="question" name="question" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; resize: none;"></textarea>
        <button id="formsubmit"> Submit</button>
    </form>
    <textarea id="response" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; resize: none;"></textarea>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#formsubmit').on("click",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();  **// need to add this line only**

                $.post("submit.php", { question: $('#question').val() }, function(data) {
                    $('#response').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>

<?php
    $q = $_POST['question'];
    echo $q;
?>
```